# Removing duplicates based on a column in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, duplicates

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156825/remove-rows-in-file-ruby/7157395#7157395). Basically there is a CSV file but with duplicate PIDs, but I cannot do the `.uniq` as this:

```
File.open("new.csv", "w+") { |file| file.puts File.readlines("old.csv").uniq }
```

since the lines are different. I'm new to Ruby and was wondering if there was an elegant way to remove the entire line just based on the first column? Or do I have to go through each row and look for duplicate PIDs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass `uniq` a block to specify on which requirement it will remove the duplicated elements.

```
File.open("old.csv", "w+") do |file|
  file.puts File.readlines("csv.csv").uniq! { |s| s[/^\d+/ ] }
end
```

As explained in the [`uniq` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Replace the `/^\d+/` regular expression by anyone that suits you.

Comment: Csv rows can span multiple lines. I recommend using the csv library instead.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say pid is the second column:

```
CSV.open('new.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  CSV.read('old.csv').uniq{|x| x[1]}.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```